# how to retrieve data in a tableview

Tags: iphone, tableview

I have succeeded in adding the data to my tableview , however in the table view it will retrieve new datas and old data will not be replaced and in the table view it would retrieve 2 of the same data i have added. Meaning i would have "test, test, hi " and when i enter a new data (bye, hello) i will have "test, test, hi, test, test, hi, bye, bye, hello"

if u need additional codes tell me so thanks .

my codes :

```
       // ---Retrieve Rows---
    -(void) getAllRowsFromTableNamed: (NSString *) tableName {
        [self openDB];
        NSString *qsql = @"SELECT * FROM Favourites";
        sqlite3_stmt *statement;

        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, [qsql UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil) ==
            SQLITE_OK) {
            // Setup the SQL Statement and compile it for faster access
            while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
            {

                // Read the data from the result row
                char *field1 = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0);
                self.field1Str = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String: field1];

                char *field2 = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1);
                self.field2Str = [[NSString    alloc] initWithUTF8String: field2];


                NSString *stringValue = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String: field1];
                [self.listArray addObject:stringValue];
                [stringValue release];

                NSLog(@"Address : %@ Description : %@", self.field1Str, self.field2Str);

            }
        }
        // Release the compiled statement from memory
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        sqlite3_close(db);
        NSLog(@"DATA RETRIEVED");
    }
    //---End of Retrieve Row---



        - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
        {
            return [self.listData count];
        }

        - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
                 cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
        {
            static NSString *TableIdentifier = @"TableIdentifier";
            UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView
                                     dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:TableIdentifier];
            if (cell == nil) {
                cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                              reuseIdentifier:TableIdentifier] autorelease];
            }

            NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
            cell.textLabel.text = [listData objectAtIndex:row];
            return cell;

        }

    - (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
        [self getAllRowsFromTableNamed:@"Favourites"];

        NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:self.field1Str, self.field2Str, nil];

        [self.listArray addObjectsFromArray:array];
        [array release];
        [favouriteListTableView reloadData];
        //NSLog(@"String1:%@, String2:%@", self.string1, self.string2); 
    }
============================================================================================
-(void) insertRecordIntoTableNamed: (NSString *) tableName
                        withField1: (NSString *) field1 field1Value: (NSString *) field1Value
                         andField2: (NSString *) field2 field2Value: (NSString *) field2Value {
    [self openDB];
    NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                     @"INSERT OR REPLACE INTO '%@' ('%@', '%@') VALUES ('%@','%@')",
                     tableName, field1, field2, field1Value, field2Value];

    char *err;
    if (sqlite3_exec(db, [sql UTF8String], NULL, NULL, &err) != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        sqlite3_close(db);
        NSAssert(0, @"Error updating table.");

    }
    NSLog(@"DATA RECORDED");

}

-(IBAction)doneButton:(id)sender {
    if([addressTextField.text isEqualToString:@""] || [descriptionTextField.text isEqualToString:@""]){
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] 
                              initWithTitle:@"Invalid Input!" 
                              message:@"Please enter Address or Description"
                              delegate:self 
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }
    else{   
    [self insertRecordIntoTableNamed:@"Favourites"
                          withField1:@"address" field1Value:addressTextField.text
                           andField2:@"description" field2Value:descriptionTextField.text]; 

    NSArray *viewControllers = [self.navigationController viewControllers];

    FavouriteListViewController *favouriteListVC = (FavouriteListViewController *)[viewControllers objectAtIndex:viewControllers.count - 2];

    [favouriteListVC setString1:self.field1Str];
    [favouriteListVC setString2:self.field2Str];
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: First check how many data you are getting from database and open your database and check how many data are stored in database?

Comment: if i add in it will be added in the data base and the amount is correct , but it only shows 2 rows at the tableview.

Comment: As SElanthiraiyan said, you have to add data in listdata array when you retrieve it.

Comment: You can see in your debug console you will get all the data. You have use addObject method while you fetch your data from database.

Comment: in Self.listData How You Adding Address....Give Your Code I Will check it out . i hope before Code In Self.listData Having Two ObjectS Only So its Showing Like That

Comment: i have edited the codes and i have met another problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the data to the listData array after retrieving them from database.

```
 while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
        {
            // Read the data from the result row
            char *field1 = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0);
            NSString *stringValue = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String: field1];
            [self.listData addObject:stringValue];
            [stringValue release];

        }
```

You are getting only rows because you have only two objects present there in the listData array.